# Finding all departments where the total salary is greater than the average of the total salary at all departments

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, relational-database

I've found similar types of question asked previously.But those are not perfect that what i want.So, I've to asked here.

I've five tables given as bellow...

```
department(dept_name,building,budget);
primary key (dept_name)

course(course_id,title,dept_name,credits);
primary key (course_id),
foreign key (dept_name) references department

instructor(id,name,dept_name,salary);
primary key (ID),
foreign key (dept_name) references department

section(course_id,sec_id,semester,year,building,room_number,time_slot_id);
primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
foreign key (course_id) references course

teaches(id,course_id,sec_id,semester,year);
primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
foreign key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year) references section,
foreign key (ID) references instructor
```

Now I am finding all departments where the total salary is greater than the average of the total salary 
at all departments using this query.

```
with dept_total (dept_name, value) as
(select dept_name, sum(salary)
from instructor
group by dept_name),
dept_total_avg(value) as
(select avg(value)
from dept_total)
select dept_name
from dept_total, dept_total_avg
where dept_total.value >= dept_total_avg.value;
```

What will be the equivalent query without using the with clause which is provide the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the correct query.So,the equivalent query without using the with clause will be this.

```
select dept_name
from (
    select dept_name, sum(salary) dept_total
    from instructor
    group by dept_name
), (
    select avg(dept_total) dept_total_avg
    from (
        select dept_name, sum(salary) dept_total
        from instructor
        group by dept_name
    )
) where dept_total >= dept_total_avg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the HAVING clause will allow this, the following SQL is untested but should work...

```
SELECT d.dept_name,
    SUM(salary) AS DeptTotalSalary,
    SUM(salary) / COUNT(*) AS DeptAverageSalary
FROM department d
JOIN instructor i ON i.dept_name d.dept_name
GROUP BY d.dept_name
HAVING DeptAverageSalary > DeptTotalSalary
```

Answer (score 0):

I had no change to test but something like this should work.

```
SELECT dept_name FROM instructor 
GROUP BY dept_name
HAVING SUM(salary)>=
(SELECT AVG(dept_sum.SumSalary) AS AvgSalary FROM 
    (
        SELECT dept_name, sum(salary) as SumSalary FROM instructor
        GROUP BY dept_name
    ) as dept_sum
)
```

Comment: it says , `ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` after running this query.

Comment: Although I don't find any parenthesis missing here.